Why is my http request with API not working with GCL cloud functions?
I'm trying to build a google cloud function with a HTTP API request, but it looks like it's not working.
What i've tried:

Already double checked API key if it's correct (API key is generated by Google cloud console)
Check if I have all required imports
Tried without the API and it worked

from google.cloud import firestore
import datetime
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def update_visitor_count(request):
    # Extract API key from query parameters
    api_key = request.args.get('api_key')

    # Validate API key (example: compare with a known API key)
    if api_key != 'MY_API_KEY':
        return 'Unauthorized', 401  # Unauthorized status code

    # Initialize Firestore client
    db = firestore.Client(project="MY_PROJECT_ID", database="db-test")
    
    # Get today's date
    today_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()

    # Get reference to the document for today's date
    doc_ref = db.collection('visitor_stats').document(today_date)

    # Get current visitor count for today
    doc = doc_ref.get()
    if doc.exists:
        current_count = doc.to_dict().get('count', 0)
    else:
        current_count = 0

    # Increment visitor count by 1
    new_count = current_count + 1

    # Update Firestore document with new count
    doc_ref.set({'count': new_count})

    return f'Visitor counts updated to {new_count} for {today_date}'

This was the one I was doing without API and it worked.
from google.cloud import firestore
import datetime
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def update_visitor_count(request):
    # Initialize Firestore client
    db = firestore.Client(project="MY_PROJECT_ID", database="db-test")
    
    # Get today's date
    today_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()

    # Get reference to the document for today's date
    doc_ref = db.collection('visitor_stats').document(today_date)

    # Get current visitor count for today
    doc = doc_ref.get()
    if doc.exists:
        current_count = doc.to_dict().get('count', 0)
    else:
        current_count = 0

    # Increment visitor count by 1
    new_count = current_count + 1

    # Update Firestore document with new count
    doc_ref.set({'count': new_count})

    return f'Visitor counts updated to {new_count} for {today_date}'

Any help or direction would be much appreciated

I'm confused. Generally you don't want to be using API keys (for Google's services); API keys authenticate apps and, as bearer tokens, are discouraged. That said, some Google APIs (which do you want?) do require API keys. The difference between your code is that one variant expects an api_key property in the request and the other does not. You don't include the use of this function that includes the value for api_key nor any correlation between that value and the API key that you created.

What do you mean by 'not working'? Do you have an error? exception?
